# How to edit multiple embedded documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to find objects that match the following query and then set the events property to an empty array if it matches. Currently the query I'm using will only update the first embedded object in each document, but I need it to check every embedded object in each document. Here is the query, does anyone know how I can make this work?

```
const date_check = moment().subtract(10, 'minutes').format('X')

await Accumulator.updateMany(
    { 'data.lastUpdate': { $lt: date_check } },
    { 
        $set: {
            'data.$.events': []
        }
    }
)
```

The document looks like this...

```
{
    bookmaker: 'Bet365',
    sport: 'Football',
    data: [
        {
            lastUpdate: '2372273273',
            events: [
                ... // some event objects
            ]
        },
        {
            lastUpdate: '2372234421',
            events: [
                ... // some event objects
            ]
        },
        {
            lastUpdate: '2375343461',
            events: [
                ... // some event objects
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its best to change your schema so `lastUpdate` to be a number
for perfomance, and to avoid bugs, check `$toInt`, you can do it with code similar to the second query.

Query

- arrayfilters way
- replace "2372273273" with date_check
- filter to keep the documents
- use arrayFilters to make the change only the member-documents that pass the filter

```js
db.collection.update({
  "data.lastUpdate": {
    "$lt": "2372273273"
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "data.$[data].events": []
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "data.lastUpdate": {
        "$lt": "2372273273"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Query

- alternative pipeline update way with `$map`
- replace "2372273273" with `date_check`
- filter to find the document
- update only the members that the filter is true

> pipeline update requires MongoDB >= 4.2

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49a0)

```js
db.collection.update({
  "data.lastUpdate": {
    "$lt": "2372273273"
  }
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "data": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$data",
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$lt": [
                  "$$this.lastUpdate",
                  "2372273273"
                ]
              },
              {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$this",
                  {
                    "events": []
                  }
                ]
              },
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I keep getting the 'Could not find path "data.0.lastUpdate" in schema at castArrayFilters' error when I use the first query you suggested, do you know anything about this?

Comment: 2nd one works though, so I'll go with that. Thank you

Comment: in all examples that i tested it seems ok, if you find example that doesnt work if you can post it on mongoplayground, and send the link, maybe its fixable in easy way